# Dailymotion API -"Unsufficient scope" Error

Tags: php, api, motion, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to build a form that uploads videos to my Dailymotion account.

I built the code myself using the documentation, and I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DailymotionAuthRequiredException'
>   with message 'Unsufficient scope for `POST /videos', scope required:
>   manage_videos, write, delete'

I tried using the script here: http://easyscript4u.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-upload-video-on-dailymotion.html

And I get the same error. I looked up the error, and it seems as though you need a token. The documentation doesn't say anything about needing this if you have the password, and that tutorial seemed to work for that dude just fine without it.

I'm thinking this may be a new feature they added so it isn't fully documented. My question is just how do I get a token for this type of request(when I have the user password and everything), and where would I plug it in to the linked script?

Thank you for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in your error, you need the manage_videos, write and delete scopes to be able to upload a video on Dailymotion. This is detailed in http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/authentication.html#requesting-extended-permissions : your application needs to request some specific permissions to its user.

Hence, the line you should change in the code you mention is the following:

```
$api->setGrantType(
    Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD,
    $apiKey,
    $apiSecret,
    array('write', 'delete', 'manage_videos'),
    array('username' => $testUser, 'password' => $testPassword)
);
```

It should make it work.